# Create review in two scopes at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two types of users, one that can create movies and one that can create reviews:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :created_movies, foreign_key: 'creator_id', class_name: 'Movie'
  has_many :reviewed_movies, foreign_key: 'reviewer_id', class_name: 'Review'
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :reviewer, class_name: 'User'
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
end
```

What I want to do is create the particular review and set the reviewer_id to the current_user at once. Here is my code for Review#create:

```
  def create
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
    @review = @movie.reviews.merge(current_user.reviewed_movies).create(review_params)
    if @review.save
.
.
.
end
```

This does not make sense to me as I do have current_user defined in my SessionsHelper and have 'include SessionsHelper' in my application controller. Code for current_user:

```
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end
```

I've been stuck on this problem for a couple hours and would appreciate any assistance on how I can get past it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will create the new review and assign it to the `current_user`:

```
def create
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
    @review = @movie.reviews.build(review_params)
    @review.reviewer = current_user
    if @review.save
      # ...
end
```

or alternatively:

```
def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
    @review.reviewer = current_user
    if @review.save
      # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply collimarco. I substituted in your code, created a new review, then went to the command line and typed:[13] pry(main)> r = Review.last
  Review Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "reviews".* FROM "reviews"  ORDER BY "reviews"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
#<Review:0x007fa73fdc1d40> {
             :id => 7,
         :rating => 5,
          :title => "bbbbbbbb",
        :content => "bbbbbbbbmmmmmmm",
     :created_at => Wed, 16 Sep 2015 19:30:13 UTC +00:00,
     :updated_at => Wed, 16 Sep 2015 19:30:13 UTC +00:00,
       :movie_id => 3,
    :reviewer_id => nil
}
[14] pry(main)> r.reviewer
nil

Comment: It doesn't populate for some reason. :reviewer_id is still nil and calling r.reviwer returns nil. Any idea on whats happening?

Comment: Maybe is a problem with `current_user`? Are you sure it is defined? Try to add `p current_user` just above `@review.reviewer = current_user` and see in console if it prints the user (as expected) or nil.

Comment: You can also try using `@review.reviewer_id = current_use.id` but it's the same.

Comment: Nevermind, your code worked! Part of the problem was that I was not authenticating the user before creating the review so it had no way of getting the id to begin with. Rookie mistake. Thanks for your help collimarco.